# Ruby on Rails - Execute ajax to render partial on JQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

I am trying to render a partial after a user clicks a button.

However the following will download the partial html immediately and not after the click:

```
$('#menu_signup').click(function(){
        $('#fade-wrapper').fadeIn();
        $('#fade-wrapper').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/signup', :remote => true) %>");
    });
```

I can't use the `link_to` tag because the button does more in the click than calling only the ajax.

Is there a way to execute the ajax in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up using basic JQuery Ajax:

```
$('#menu_signup').click(function(){
        $('#fade-wrapper').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({url: "/signup_login", format: 'js', success: function(result){
        }});

    });
```

With a JS:

```
$('#fade-wrapper').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'signup_form', formats: [:html]) %>");
```